# How Can I Create a 2D Silicon Carbide Structure using VESTA

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, band-structure, density-of-states, vesta

I'm just getting started with VESTA. SO I'm fairly new to it. Can anyone suggest me how to build a 2D structure of Silicon Carbide (SiC)? Or any documentation would also help.
Thanks .

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: As far as I know, VESTA is only for visualization, it doesn't do structure editions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.